# Symfony forms - password type

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-forms

When I am trying to add password filed in my form type class:

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder->add('name', 'text');
    $builder->add('email', 'email');
    $builder->add('password', 'password');

    $builder->add('terms', 'checkbox', array(
        'mapped' => false,
        'constraints' => new NotBlank()
    ));
}
```

and then render this field in twig template `{{ form_row(register.password) }}` it appears like text filed. But I need it to be the password type `<input type='password'..`.

Also form type is attached to entity with password attribute:

```
/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="password", type="string", length=32, nullable=false)
 */
private $password;
```

What is the reason?

Comment: Do you use a form theme? If that's the case the default widget might be overridden. Can you try `{{ form_widget(register.password) }}` and see what happens?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason is that I use form theme:

```
{% block text_row %}
<div>

    {{ block('form_label') }}

    <div>
        {{ block('form_widget_simple') }}
    </div>

</div>
{% endblock %}
```

So I add new block:

```
{% block password_row %}
<div>

    {{ block('form_label') }}

    <div>
        {{ block('password_widget') }}
    </div>

</div>
{% endblock %}
```

And now all is OK

Answer (score 2):

You should use Type to define field Type in `$builder->add('child', 'type', ...)`

```
$builder->add('username', TextType::class, array('label' => 'Username'))
        ->add('password', PasswordType::class, array('label' => 'Password'))
```

and in Twig

```
{{ form(form) }}
```

Answer (score -1):

Not sure if this is the correct way, but did you try specifying a type to the field?

```
$builder->add('password', 'password', array('type'=>'password');
```